# pyqtdeploy: Fails when configuring qt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, ubuntu-18.04, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to compile a pyqt5 application following the pyqtdeploy documentation but no success.

When running build-demo.py, it produces an error when qt is been configured.
I have downloaded all the correct and required tarballs for demo.

Also, if i compile qt separately, it works just fine following this https://www.ics.com/blog/how-compile-qt-source-code-linux.

Running this,

python3 build-demo.py --verbose

I get the following error:

pyqtdeploy-sysroot: Execution failed: returned exit code 3

I wonder if I am missing any command configure options or libraries.
Any help will be greatly Appreciated

I'm using python 3 on ubuntu 18